# Runs in PHP7 whats wrong for use with php 5.3?

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.3

I use the following in php7 and it works fine. Why will it not work in php 5.3?

```
function convertDateTime($unixTime) {
  $dt = new DateTime("@$unixTime");
  return $dt->format('YmdHis');
}

$prettydate = convertDateTime(time ());
```

edit1----

turnining on debugging give me this error

```
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CDT/-5.0/DST' instead' in /var/www/test/makenew.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/test/makenew.php(11): DateTime->__construct('@1534017729') #1 /var/www/test/makenew.php(14): convertDateTime(1534017729) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/test/makenew.php on line 11"
```

So this question remains half answered as I see it as I am not sure how to implement one of these methods. Interesting that php7 does not give this error

edit2----

adding date_default_timezone_set() works so for php 5.3 it looks like I must use

```
$timezone= 'America/Los_Angeles';

function convertDateTime($unixTime) {
  date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
  $dt = new DateTime("@$unixTime");
  return $dt->format('YmdHis');
}

$prettydate = convertDateTime(time ());
```

It would seem to me though it would be better to get the timezone from the OS and set the $timezone variable based on that

This also seems to work:

```
date_default_timezone_set(@date_default_timezone_get());
```

It does not know the "real" time zone only the offset. Right now it believes Time Zone is CDT chicago when it IS CDT but not chicago yielding the correct time anyway. It is the offset that is important, not the city.

Comment: Is there an error message you can include in your question?

Comment: I don't think the issue is version specific, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f4a03d9966077646c83403f5efe56aa2a5c4a8b. Please add the error.

Comment: i tried it on local server with php 5.6 and it is working..... check if timezone is set or add manually like date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");

Comment: Runs fine on 5.3 for me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b2d0db80d58bd8223c37bc91f64c82aa78307b3. Can you please provide more detail than "will not work"? In what way does it not work? Update yer question with the rest of the info pls.

Comment: Actually when i put this on the 5.3 server The page no longer loads at all. It "breaks" the page just pasting it into php. Will turn on debugging see if that tells me anything useful.

Comment: Right, but what @user3783243 and I were saying was it's not intrinsically *that code* that has a problem, as it can and will run fine. This was your cue to investigate things other than the code itself, which you did, and you found the problem by the looks.

Comment: Please do accept the answer if it sorted out your issue :) Alternatively, provide the answer that resolved your issue

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to put the timezone in a configuration line in your php.ini file. You should have a block like this in your php.ini file:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

If not, add it (**replacing the timezone by yours**). After configuring, make sure to restart httpd (service httpd restart).